# Can't use indexOf and includes on innerHTML value

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml, indexof

i have a problem with a content of a div:

```
//d = document.getElementsByClassName("myclass")
//R = is an array and contains 'question' and other words
//d[u].innerHTML = 'Hi, this is a question'
//R[i] = 'question'
var inner = d[u].innerHTML;
alert(inner.indexOf(R[i]));//result -1
alert(inner.includes(R[i]));//result false
```

Why can't i see positiive reply?

Edit:

```
var inner = d[u].innerHTML;
alert(R[i]);//this alert is: question
alert(inner.indexOf('question'));//result >-1
alert(inner.includes('question'));//result true
```

Now work, but i lose my array... how can I fix it?
Apparently indexOf and includes don't want variables????

Edit:
The problem is the R[i] value:

```
if R[i] = id="05" : error(indexOf -1); if R[i] = id=05 : correct (indexOf > -1);
```

But i must use "" or '', it is very important, how can i fix this problem?

Comment: what is  `d` and `R` ?

Comment: Could it be that the problem lies somewhere else in your code? Are `d[u].innerHTML` and `R[i]` both of type String?

Comment: d = document.getElementsByClassName("myclass") and R[i] is an element of an array: R['question','others..']

Comment: It does work with variables. Check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hv6jrqrx/ problem is somewhere else in your code

Comment: try to see this update: https://jsfiddle.net/hv6jrqrx/5/ in this example don't work and this is my real problem

Answer (score 0):

The `indexOf()` method returns the position of the first occurrence of a specified value in a string.
This method returns -1 if the value to search for never occurs.
**Note**: The `indexOf()` method is case sensitive.

You could put all instances of `myclass` inside of `inner`

```js
var d = document.getElementsByClassName("myclass"),
    dlen = d.length,
    u;
var R = ['question', 'paragraph', 'answer'],
    Rlen = R.length,
    i;
var inner = "";
for(u=0;u<dlen;u+=1){
  inner += d[u].innerText + " ";
}
for(i=0;i<Rlen;i+=1){
  console.log(inner.indexOf(R[i]));
  console.log(inner.includes(R[i]));
  console.log("---");
}
```

```html
<div class="myclass">word</div>
<div class="myclass">text</div>
<div class="myclass">paragraph</div>
<div class="myclass">letters</div>
<div class="myclass">characters</div>
```